# Form with multiple action?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this thymleaf page:

```
<form method="post" action="#" th:object="${userData}"  >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label th:text="#{manageusers.firstnamelabel}">Surname</label></td>
            <td><input required="required" type="text" th:field="*{Firstname}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label th:text="#{manageusers.lastnamelabel}">Lastname</label></td>
            <td><input required="required" type="text" th:field="*{Lastname}" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <input type="submit" name="back" value="Back"/>
    <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm"/>
</form>
```

What I want is different action (ie. different page controller action) based on submit button clicked. Is there a way I can handle this in thymeleaf or spring boot (In my controller class)?

Comment: You can change the form action by using javascript.

Comment: @ControlAltDel please, don't use that design, it's very hard to maintain in the long term.

Comment: Add this to your buttons, if you want a quick fix. `onClick="self.location='Your_URL_here.htm'"`. But use java script functions for better design and code.

Comment: @K139 That doesn't submit the form, it redirects the page (without submission). He's looking to submit to a different action based on a button element being clicked.

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to change the form action, you want different handler methods depending on the button pressed.

back:

```
@RequestMapping( value="/your-url", method=POST, params={"back"} )
```

confirm:

```
@RequestMapping( value="/your-url", method=POST, params={"confirm"} )
```

Personally I name my buttons `btnX`, so as to differentiate them from model attribute field names.

Also, use `<button type=submit>` instead of `<input type=submit>` as this lets you specify name, text and value.

While we're at it, don't use html tables for layouts. Try Bootstrap.